# Janela ao clicar no botão html

Tags: html, css

Olá, e
Estou criando uma área em meu site, em que quando a pessoa clicasse em "mostra mais" abriria uma janela no próprio site , mostrando o conteúdo como na imagem abaixo, mas não tenho ideia em como fazer , poderiam me auxiliar ?

Comment: Kd a imagem? :p

Comment: desculpe esqueci de colocar, mas é exatamente como o @julio fez abaixo

Comment: Mas aquele é um modal do bootstrap. Vc tah usando Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um exemplo de modal funcional:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      Mostrar mais
    </button>
    
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
           // Aqui você irá colocar os códigos html que vão preencher o corpo do seu modal
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Para o css utilizei o bootstrap pois ja contem classes prontas, mas você pode usar qualquer outra classe para stilos.

Comment: para esse esse codigo funcionar eu precisa ter o bootstrap instalado ?

Comment: se vc usar os links que eu botei, ele ja "instala", mas vc pode substituir algumas classes que daria certo em tese

Comment: conseguir adicionar o modal e esta funcionando , tenho 5 modal , quando clico sobre o "mostrar mas " o conteúdo fica igual para todos

Comment: sim, vc precisa alterar o conteudo de cada um

Comment: Obrigado, é possível alterar o tamanho do modal ?

Comment: é sim use o width e height do css